# can I use Laravel code in css style?

Tags: css, laravel-5, styles, inline

In order to develop a CMS I have to provide users the facility of changing design. hence I don't know the way that's how I can use the data after retrieving from database.. For instance, if the user want the background color black and change the font-size .. then I have to write the code like (I don't know how to write the laravel code in style but I am given it here to make the question understood):

```
<div style="background-color:{{$queryResult->bgColor}};font-size:{{$queryResult->fontSize}}"></div>
```

Comment: is it different than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47740264/8927508) ?

Comment: you can set flags for the page and on the basis of flags you have to set code inside the conditions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any method in Laravel to use in style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740264/is-there-any-method-in-laravel-to-use-in-style)

Comment: I could not explain what I wanted to mean in the previous question, that's why this is the new one. Sorry for that Rishi Raut

Comment: don't say `sorry`, just add more detail about what you are getting and what you want ? As more related detail you will provide it is easy to understand others

Comment: Also did you get any changes after update ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `background-color:` and `font-size:`, May be you just adding the value

```
<div style="background-color:{{$queryResult->bgColor}}; font-size:{{$queryResult->fontSize}}"></div>
```

Comment: I want to add the bgColor code and font-size here from database using Controller

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this line of code to display active class on menu while i'm on the page so may be this code direct you to do what you want.

```
<li class="{{ isset($data["page-tab"]) && ($data["page-tab"] == "list_user") || ($data["page-tab"] == "create_user") ? "active treeview" : "treeview" }}"></li>
```

in this $data['page-tab'] this value passed from my controller

and in the blade template i just check if value is comming than active class is used in that otherwise not.

so may i hope this leads to solve your problem